# Getting the average from a user entered array

Tags: c#

Hi I am trying to make a program that ask the user to enter up to 25 numbers and then displays the average for them but when It asks for the number it just keeps asking for numbers over ans over again and doesn't display the average.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("enter the amount of numbers you would like to find the average and mean of: ");
        int arraylength = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] AverageArray = new int[25];


        //filling the array with user input
        for (int i = 0; i < AverageArray.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("enter the numbers you wish to find the average for: ");
            AverageArray[i] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        }
        //printing out the array 
        Console.WriteLine("here is your array: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < AverageArray.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(AverageArray[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(FindAverage(AverageArray));
    }


    public static double FindAverage(int[] averageNumbers)
    {
        int arraySum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < averageNumbers.Length; i++)
            arraySum += averageNumbers[i];

        return arraySum / averageNumbers.Length;
    }

}
```

Comment: First off, AverageArry should be initialized using the array length so int[] AverageArray = new int[arraylength];   Then it will loop thrugh an amount of times equal to your length, asking for each number one at a time. Are you saying it is never leaving this for loop?

Comment: practically word for word!

Comment: @Kritner the problem seems to be with his looping, not the actual finding of the average

Comment: @Kritner HAHA holy crap i just looked at your linked thread XD that is an exact copy paste :P.

Comment: @psoshmo I just thought I was in the matrix for a second.  As I know a very similar question had come in I commented on previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you already have `arrayLength`, why not use that as your array size indicator? Also, your average routine will lose precision. You are returning `double`, but your code has everything as `int`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("enter the amount of numbers you would like to find the average and mean of: ");
    int arraylength = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int[] AverageArray = new int[arraylength];

    //filling the array with user input
    for (int i = 0; i < arraylength; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("enter the numbers you wish to find the average for: ");
        AverageArray[i] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    //printing out the array 
    Console.WriteLine("here is your array: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(AverageArray[i]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(FindAverage(AverageArray));
}

public static double FindAverage(int[] averageNumbers)
{
    // change to 'double' otherwise you will lose precision
    double arraySum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < averageNumbers.Length; i++)
        arraySum += averageNumbers[i];

    return arraySum / averageNumbers.Length;
}
```